# Получение ответа от виджета youtube

Tags: jquery, youtube, виджет

Использую на сайте код сгенерированный с официальной страницы google виджет youtube для сайтов и мне нужно отследить подписку и отписку, но скрипт не работает:

Изначальная версия:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<script>
  function onYtEvent(payload) {
    if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
      // Add code to handle subscribe event.
    } else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
      // Add code to handle unsubscribe event.
    }
    if (window.console) { // for debugging only
      window.console.log('YT event: ', payload);
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="alfagametv" data-layout="full" data-count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>
```

Немного его переделал:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function onYtEvent(b) {
    if (b.eventType == 'subscribe') {
      alert('Подписка');
    } else if (b.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
      alert('Отписка');
    }
    if (window.console) { // for debugging only
      window.console.log('YT event: ', b);
    }
  });
</script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="alfagametv" data-layout="full" onclick="onYtEvent(payload);" data-count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>
```

В первом случае код вообще не вызывает функцию для отслеживания подписки или отписки.

Во втором случае в консоли выводится

```
YT event: function  (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)}
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

**Обновление**

Я сделал все, что вы предложили, вот ответ логов `YT event`:

```
function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Уберите `onclick="onYtEvent(payload);"`, а также убедитесь, что у юзера не приватные подписки в настройках.